# Can solutions that we get from a direction field of a Linear ODE cross each other

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

### Question:

When we sketch the direction fields of a given Linear ODE, can they cross each other ?

#### Reasoning:

Let we have a linear ODE of the form
$$y'(x) = f(x,y(x))$$

This means that for a given $(x,y)$, $f(x,y)$ have a definite value, hence at that point, the derivative of any function that satisfies the linear ODE is that unique value $f(x,y)$. Therefore, if at some point we have more than one solution, the solutions cannot cross each (they can meet, but not cross) other because that would violate the uniqness of the derivative at that point as I have argued.

Now, I have asked the same question to one of my professors by giving the above argument, but he said that "we don't know the form of $f(x,y)$, so we cannot sure such a thing", however, my argument directly eliminates his argument in my view, but I want to make sure that the above argument is a valid argument and my conclusion is correct.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous and differentiable?

Comment: For $y'=-\sqrt{\max(y,0)}$ the solutions with $y(0)=0$ and $y(0)=1$ meet in finite time.

Comment: @Rahul I have no idea what you mean by "meet in finite time". Plus, how can a function have more than one value at a specific point ?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, we can assume that there exists a solution $x_0$ for the sake of the question.

Comment: Let $y_0$ be the solution of $y'=-\sqrt{\max(y,0)}$ with initial condition $y(0)=0$, and let $y_1$ be the solution with $y(0)=1$. It turns out that $y_0(x)=y_1(x)$ for all $x\ge2$. The solution curves don't *cross*, but they *meet* at $x=2$ and agree after that. I don't understand the rest of your comments.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for your example, but this is just **an**  examle that you gave, and does not say anything about the validity of my argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have explain in my question:

> This means that for a given $(x,y)$, $f(x,y)$ have a definite value,
>   hence at that point, the derivative of any function that satisfies the
>   linear ODE is that unique value $f(x,y)$. Therefore, if at some point
>   we have more than one solution, the solutions cannot cross each (they
>   can meet, but not cross) other because that would violate the uniqness
>   of the derivative at that point as I have argued.